# how to create one-to-many relevance on google-app-engine

Tags: python, google-app-engine, one-to-many, listproperty

like one forum has many topic ,

ths specific is : forum  and topic has the same model :

```
class Geo(db.Model):
    #self = db.SelfReferenceProperty()
    title = db.StringProperty()
    link = db.StringProperty()
    updated = db.DateTimeProperty(auto_now =True)
    author = db.ReferenceProperty(MyUser)
    id = db.StringProperty()
    entry_keys = db.ListProperty(db.Key)
    summary = db.StringProperty(multiline=True)
    point = db.StringProperty()

    @property
    def entry(self):
        return [db.get(key) for key in self.entry_keys]
```

all they are a geo-rss format , i use ListProperty this place ,but ListProperty has max size ,

so i have to find other method,

so what i should do ,

thanks

Comment: Can you re-phrase the question in English?

Answer (score 1):

If you want a many-to-many relationship, @thethimble's suggestion is good.  If you do want a many-to-one relationship, though, you *could* use a [SelfReferenceProperty](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/typesandpropertyclasses.html#SelfReferenceProperty) from forum to topic -- like any other [ReferenceProperty](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/typesandpropertyclasses.html#ReferenceProperty), that, too, makes an implicit collection property on the referenced entity (the one, while the referencers are the many).

Answer (score 0):

This is actually a many-to-many relationship. A forum can have multiple topics. One topic can be associated with multiple forums.

Check out the [many-to-many](http://code.google.com/appengine/articles/modeling.html) section in the Google App Engine documentation.